# Why pd.read_csv get wrong value when using dtype = 'Int64'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na, int64

```py
import pandas as pd


When there is no na values, It's right.

!cat id1
```

```
1471341653427101696 1458379213265436885
```

```py
pd.read_csv('id1',sep ='\t',header=None, na_values=['\\N'],dtype = 'Int64')
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1471341653427101696 | 1458379213265436885 |

```py
!cat id2
```

```
1471870967209926656 \N
1471341653427101696 1458379213265436885
1471458498691866624 1458379213265436889
```

when using int64, and there are na values,  pd get wrong number

```py
df = pd.read_csv('id2',sep ='\t',header=None, na_values=['\\N'],dtype = 'Int64')
df
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1471870967209926656 | <NA> |
| 1471341653427101696 | 1458379213265436672 |
| 1471458498691866624 | 1458379213265436672 |

when read as str, it's correct

```py
df = pd.read_csv('id2',sep ='\t',header=None, na_values=['\\N'],dtype = 'str')
df
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1471870967209926656 | NaN |
| 1471341653427101696 | 1458379213265436885 |
| 1471458498691866624 | 1458379213265436889 |

```py
df[1]
```

```
0                    NaN
1    1458379213265436885
2    1458379213265436889
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

```py
df.loc[[0],1].astype('Int64')
```

```
0    <NA>
Name: 1, dtype: Int64
```

```py
df.loc[[1],1].astype('Int64')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/tmp/ipykernel_1971828/2578832362.py in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[[1],1].astype('Int64')


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5813         else:
   5814             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5815             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5816             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5817 


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    416 
    417     def astype(self: T, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise") -> T:
--> 418         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    419 
    420     def convert(


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    325                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    326                 else:
--> 327                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    328             except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    329                 if not ignore_failures:


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    589         values = self.values
    590 
--> 591         new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    592 
    593         new_values = maybe_coerce_values(new_values)


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy, errors)
   1307 
   1308     try:
-> 1309         new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1310     except (ValueError, TypeError):
   1311         # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_array(values, dtype, copy)
   1255 
   1256     else:
-> 1257         values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
   1258 
   1259     # in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1103     # dispatch on extension dtype if needed
   1104     if isinstance(dtype, ExtensionDtype):
-> 1105         return dtype.construct_array_type()._from_sequence(arr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
   1106 
   1107     elif not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):  # pragma: no cover


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype, copy)
    321         cls, scalars, *, dtype: Dtype | None = None, copy: bool = False
    322     ) -> IntegerArray:
--> 323         values, mask = coerce_to_array(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    324         return IntegerArray(values, mask)
    325 


~/.conda/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in coerce_to_array(values, dtype, mask, copy)
    196             "mixed-integer-float",
    197         ]:
--> 198             raise TypeError(f"{values.dtype} cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype")
    199 
    200     elif is_bool_dtype(values) and is_integer_dtype(dtype):


TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype
```

Comment: what is the question please ?

Comment: id2 ,line 2, it should be 1458379213265436885, but pd read as 1458379213265436672

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in [GH 50757](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/50757), so it works ever since [pandas v2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html):

> **What’s new in 2.0.0 (April 3, 2023)**
> ...
> Fixed bug in `Series` constructor unnecessarily overflowing for nullable unsigned integer dtypes ([GH 38798](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38798), [GH 25880](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25880))

---

For [older versions of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30268), the only way is to use `str`, remove `nan`, then convert to `int`.